# what is the limit of arctan(x/y)

Tags: calculus

What is the limit of arctan(x/y) as x,y goes 0? Using L'Hopital rule 
I'm getting +inf but arctan is bounded function.Need help

edit: i forgot to add condition. y>0

Comment: The limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist. If $x,y$ go to zero along the line $y=x$ the limit will be $\arctan(1)$ and if $x,y$ go to zero along the line $2y = x$ the limit will be $\arctan(2)$.